# Visual studio xsd set connection string to None

Tags: visual-studio, xsd, dataset, visual-studio-2017

I want to set connection string for my `DataSet` to `None`, because i use string that i build in run time. So i do not want keep fake string in app.config, just tome make `xsd` compile. Is there any way to achieve this?

If i set `None` in designer its still turn it to existing connection string from config.

I use visual studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to have the benefits of the XSD designer and be able to change the connection settings for staging and production is as follows: - NOTE: this works in VS 2012 ... think it should also in 2010 - Also, DataSets were created by dragging from the Server Explorer, which saves connection information in the class library app.config and Properties.Settings.settings which is used at design time.

1) For each DataTable, click on the TableAdapter header (below the attributes and above the methods) and look at the properties 2) Change the Connection Modifier to Public 3) Then, the code to access the table should be something like the following (where the class library is named DALib) ...

```
using DALib;
using System.Web.Configuration;

PriceData.averageSalePriceFDataTable priceTable;
DALib.PriceDataTableAdapters.averageSalePriceFTableAdapter priceAdapter
  = new DALib.PriceDataTableAdapters.averageSalePriceFTableAdapter();

priceAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString 
  =  WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;

priceTable = priceAdapter.GetData( ... parameters ...);
```

This uses the connection string in the class library for design and picks it from Web.config when running.

Hope I understood your problem correctly, let me know.